# Python C Extension + crashing after calling the python file multiple times.

Tags: python, c, extension-methods

I have been working with a Python-C Extension in which the python file passes in a list (array) to the C file, and the C file returns three doubles. 
The first time that I call my testing file (it imports the c file and calls the c function), the program works fine. However, if I call the testing file again, the program freezes and never reaches execution. 
I do not know where the problem is occurring. I have a feeling it has to do with the c file never stopping execution, if that is possible or makes sense?

Also, I am mallocing and freeing variables, so that is not an issue.

My C API looks like the following:

Thank you kindly.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "workingHyperbolic.c"

PyObject* py_fit(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* seqx;
    PyObject* seqy;
    double p[3] = {1, 1, 1};           /* Initial conditions */
    double *carrayx;
    double *carrayy;
    double c, d, a;
    int seqlen;
    int i;

    /* get argument as a sequence */
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &seqx, &seqy))                 //ParseTuple converts values from Python to C representation. By calling NULL, the appropriate extension is raised
        return NULL;
    seqx = PySequence_Fast(seqx, "argument must be iterable");
    seqy = PySequence_Fast(seqy, "argument must be iterable");
    if(!seqx)
        return 0;
    if(!seqy)
        return 0;
    /* prepare data as an array of doubles */
    seqlen = PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(seqx);            // get length of the object, assuming that the seqx is not NULL - faster than Pysequence_Size because seqx is a list or tuple
    carrayx = malloc(seqlen*sizeof(double));        //Allocates n bytes and returns a pointer of type void* to the allocated memory
    carrayy = malloc(seqlen*sizeof(double));
    if(!carrayx) {
        Py_DECREF(seqx);                                // CPython Garbage Collector uses "Reference Counting" to maintain a list of references to an object.
                                                        //If reference count fallst oz ero than garbage collector can deallocate space for that object.
        return PyErr_NoMemory(  );
    }
    if(!carrayy) {
        Py_DECREF(seqy);
        return PyErr_NoMemory(  );
    }
    for(i=0; i < seqlen; i++) {
        PyObject *fitemx;
        PyObject *fitemy;
        PyObject *itemx = PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM(seqx, i);            //Return the sequence seqx as a list,
        PyObject *itemy = PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM(seqy, i);
        if(!itemx) {
            Py_DECREF(seqx);
            free(carrayx);
            return 0;
        }
        if(!itemy) {
            Py_DECREF(seqy);
            free(carrayy);
            return 0;
        }
        fitemx = PyNumber_Float(itemx);                 //Returns the itemx converted to a float object on success,
        fitemy = PyNumber_Float(itemy);
        if(!fitemx) {
            Py_DECREF(seqx);
            free(carrayx);
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "all items must be numbers");
            return 0;
        }
        if(!fitemy) {
            Py_DECREF(seqy);
            free(carrayy);
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "all items must be numbers");
            return 0;
        }
        carrayx[i] = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(fitemx);             //Returns the C double value of Python float x, very fast, without error checking.
        carrayy[i] = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(fitemy);             //Returns the C double value of Python float x, very fast, without error checking.
        PyErr_Occurred();
        Py_XDECREF(fitemx);
        Py_XDECREF(fitemy);
    }

    /* clean up, compute, and return result */
    Py_DECREF(seqx);
    Py_DECREF(seqy);
    c = getParameters(carrayx, carrayy, p, 'c');
    d = getParameters(carrayx, carrayy, p, 'd');
    a = getParameters(carrayx, carrayy, p, 'a');
    printf("\n%lf", c);
    printf("\n%lf", d);
    printf("\n%lf", a);
    free(carrayx);
    free(carrayy);
    return Py_BuildValue("ddd", c,d,a);         // creates python objects FROM C data type to return result back to Python. 
}

// static PyObject *_raise_error(PyObject *py_fit) {
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Vaue Error");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_BaseException, "Base Error");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_Exception, "Exception");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ArithmeticError, "Arithmetic");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_LookupError, "PyExc_LookupError");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_AssertionError, "PyExc_AssertionError");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_AttributeError, "PyExc_AttributeError");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_BlockingIOError, "PyExc_BlockingIOError");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_FloatingPointError, "PyExc_FloatingPointError.");
    // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_EOFError, "PyExc_EOFError");
    // return Py_RETURN_NONE;
// }

/* DECLARATION OF METHODS*/
 PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"fit",(PyCFunction)py_fit, METH_VARARGS, "Descirption"},
    {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}
};

// Module Definition Structure
 struct PyModuleDef fittermod = {
   PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,"fit", NULL, -1, methods
};
```

Comment: If `carrayy` is `NULL` and `carrayx` is not you might leak resources, in a python extensions that can be really bad.

Comment: @iharob: what do you mean by carrayy is Null and carrayx isn't?

Comment: You make the same mistake over and over. I would rewrite the whole function. If `itemx` is `NULL` you `free()` `carrayx` but you don't `free()` `carrayy`, also you call `PyError_Occurred()` when it apparently have been successful. Also post the python code, I suspect you are not passing a sequence but a list.

Comment: @iharob: thank you, but I don't quite understand. I thought that if I check one is Null,l then I free that one and quit the program.

Comment: Quit the program? It's not exactly a program it's a python extension. That's why when I see `if (x == NULL) exit(1);` I think!!! This is wrong, they should handle everything and exit cleanly or continue if possible. Before returning from the function you should `free()` every think you've `malloc()`ed or else a memory leak will occur and you can't do anything about it except consume more and more memory until there is no more memory. If a pointer is `NULL` you don't really need to `free()` it.

Comment: @iharob. Thank you for the comment. I'll try to understand the extension a bit more I think. I do free the variables that I malloc. Also, if I comment out all the conditional statements (if(!itemx)) etc), I still encounter the same problem. I'm not sure what is the cause of the problem, though.

Comment: They obvious way forward is to strip your extension to a "Hello World" type and then slowly build it up again.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! I solved my problem by starting all over again. I was passing in a parameter that was incompatible with the c function inside my program! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone! The problem was passing in an incompatible parameter (the parameter p) with my other c routine.